# LineSeries Chart Point Size Reduction

Tags: wpf, charts, data-visualization

I want to reduce the point/marker size in this WPF Toolkit LineSeries Chart. 
This is my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DashedPolyLine" TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">
            <Setter Property= "StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Convergence Plot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" Title="Values" UseLayoutRounding="True" PolylineStyle="{StaticResource DashedPolyLine}"/>
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"  Maximum="1.5" Minimum="-1.5" Interval="0.2"/>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
         </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

This is what I mean:

[image: WPF]

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps anyone I used this code to remove the points:

```
<Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

The setVisibility property doesn't work and it's a known issue.